Proving Normality of Ln(X) where dX follows a Geometric Brownian Motion
Nothing out of the ordinary here. Let the stochastic differential equation (SDE) of $X$ be
\begin{align*}
dX_{t} = \mu X_{t}dt + \sigma X_{t}\ dW,
\end{align*}
where $dW \sim N(0, dt)$. Through Itô's Lemma the solution in $X_{t}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
X_{t} = X_{0}e^{\left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} \right)t + \sigma W_{t}}
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
\ln(X_{t}) = \ln(X_{0}) + \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} \right)t + \sigma W_{t}.
\end{align*}
I want to find the probability distribution of $Y=\ln(X_{t})$. Usually, I resort to finding the probability density function that would provide me with (i) the form of the function; (ii) given (i) - the mean; (iii) given (i) - the variance.
I can show that
\begin{align*}
P(Y_{t}=y)&=P\left(\ln(X_{0}) + \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2} \right)t + \sigma W_{t}=y\right) \\
&= P\left(W_{t} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\left(y-\left(\ln(X_{0})+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)t\right)\right)\right)
\end{align*}
Given that $W_{t} \sim N(0,t)$, it would mean that
\begin{align*}
P\left(W_{t} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\left(y-\left(\ln(X_{0})+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)t\right)\right)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(y-\left(\ln(X_{0})+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)t\right)\right)}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}\right)^{2}\right).
\end{align*}
This would appear Normal, and I would be able to conclude that $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\ln(X_{0})+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)t$, but I cannot conclude a value of $\mathbb{V}[Y]$ given that there's a missing $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ in the coefficient.
What am I doing wrong?

You are missing a factor of the 'Jacobian' when you are performing a change of variables to get the density. Since we are working with continuous random variables it is in general good practice to work with distribution functions instead of densities.
It is known that, for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ and $Y = \sigma X + b$, we have $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(b,\sigma^2 t)$. In your problem, $b = \ln(X_0) + (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}) t $.
To see this, we compute the distribution function:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(W_t \leq \frac{1}{\sigma}(y-b)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\sigma^{-1}(y-b)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left ( -\frac{x^2}{2t} \right ) dx. $$
To recover the density, you differentiate with respect to $y$. The fundamental theorem of calculus gets you the expression you derived, but you also need the chain rule to differentiate $\sigma^{-1}(y-b)$, which gives you the extra factor of $1/\sigma$ that you were missing in order to recover the correct density (this is the extra 'Jacobian' term).

Thank you. I've learn that the continuous nature of the random variables insists working with cumulative distribution functions ($F_{X}$). Thereon - derivative operations will yield the desired results. Also - is there a typo in your answer where $dt$ should be replaced by $dx$?

@GustavoLouisG.Montańo Yes, apologies, it should be $dx$-- I've corrected the typo now.

Great, @Julius! Thanks again for your prompt help. Kudos to you, Sir!
